# Why am I not able to use modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I Do not get why it does not see the function adder from the module in the file called modulefile1.

Here is the code written in the file called modulefile1:

```
var adder = function(a, b) {
  return 'the sum of the two number is ${a + b}'
}
module.exports.adder = adder;
```

On the other file in which I am trying to use a function from the module:

```
var stuff = require('./modulefile1');
console.log(stuff.adder(1,2));
```

I get an error message that says: TypeError: stuff.adder is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your snippet works fine. Did you save it?**

Riajul & NullDev are not exporting the adder function but exporting the adder function as default export.

Check the difference between named exports and default exports.

Comment: Oh! turn out I did not save it. happens

Answer (score 1):

Use this snipet and run again thanks

```
var adder = function(a, b) {
    return 'the sum of the two number is ${a + b}'
}
module.exports = adder;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your module like:

`moduleName.function()` instead of `moduleName()` you can export an object literal:

```
var adder = function(a, b) {
    return `the sum of the two number is ${a + b}`;
};
module.exports = {
    adder
};
```

If that doesn't matter, use [@Riajul Islam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5207942/riajul-islam)'s approach with

```
module.exports = adder;
```

Comment: @RajmondX: Not valid since by default `module.exports` is undefined. So he is actually trying to do `undefined.adder = adder` which should be an error

Comment: module.exports is not undefined by default (in node environments). And yes `undefined.whatever` should _already before_ throw an error.